# How to update ImageButton BackgroundColor in RemoteViews

Tags: android

I have an appwidget which has got a ImageButton.I can update ImageButton image but i can't update backgroundcolor with using setInt() method;because imagebutton setBackgroundColor is not annoated with **RemotableViewMethod.class**.What can i do else?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setInt%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29

Example:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.view_id, "setBackgroundColor", 0xFF0000FF);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a different layout in your `RemoteViews` constructor that has the right background color. You create a `RemoteViews` object on every update, and you tell that `RemoteViews` object what layout to use. From my testing, if you inflate something different than before, that will replace what the app widget presently uses. The various `RemoteViews` setters are for things that you cannot readily handle via layouts (e.g., dynamic text for a `TextView`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageView` instead of layout background, we can set `ImageView` src to change background (may be  you will use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`)